# Calling multiple functions

Tags: haskell, boolean

I've been trying to call other functions into my main function which will return "valid" if the boolean value is True. The problem is that one of my functions returns a false value and since the others are True, am not receiving the expected output.

```
import Data.Char(isLower)

charact :: String -> Bool
charact = not . any (`elem` "! #$%&'*+-/><=?^`{|}:,``[]];")

repeatedLocal :: [Char] -> Bool
repeatedLocal [] = False
repeatedLocal (x:xs) = if elem x ['.','_'] then elem x xs else  repeatedLocal xs

lowerCase :: [Char] -> Bool
lowerCase x = if all isLower x then True else False

num :: String -> Bool
num = any (`elem` "0123456789")

localPart ::[Char] -> String
localPart [] = "E-mail Invalido"
localPart (x:xs) | length (x:xs) <= 24 && charact (x:xs) && lowerCase (x:xs) && num (x:xs) == True = "E-mail Valido"
                 | repeatedLocal (x:xs) == False = "E-mail Invalido"
                 | otherwise = localPart xs
```

The `localPart` is a function that I will apply on my main, which will validate if the boolean values from each function are True. The `charact` will validate if the strings have any type of special characters and filter it to not return True if the String has a special character.

For the `repeatedLocal` it should check if the specific values repeat more than 1 time in a string - This is part of the code where the value instead of returning True, the function return False if the string doesn't have the specific value which is '.' and '_' instead return True if the characters repeat in the string.

the `lowerCase` is to return True if the String is lowercase and `num` if there is a number in the string

The expected output should be, if the `charact` && `lowerCase` && `num` are True then the String is valid and if `repeatedLocal` is True the string is invalid

Comment: `if condition then True else False` is just a long way to write `condition`.

Comment: `condition == True` can be written as `condition`; `condition == False` as `! condition`.

Comment: Why does `localPart` return one of two arbitrary strings instead of returning a `Bool` (or better yet, a custom type like `data AddressValidity = EmailValid | EmailInvalid` that's isomorphic to `Bool`)?

Comment: aside from all the above comments - which while correct are just about code style - I don't actually know what you are saying is *wrong* with your code. Can you explain what the intended logic of the function is, together with an example input where it gives an output you're not expecting?

Comment: and if none of them are true then you delete the first character and check again?

Answer (score 0):

```hs
import Data.Char(isLower)

charact :: String -> Bool
charact = not . any (`elem` "! #$%&'*+-/><=?^`{|}:,``[]];")

repeatedLocal :: [Char] -> Bool
repeatedLocal [] = False
repeatedLocal (x:xs) = if elem x ['.','_'] then elem x xs else  repeatedLocal xs

lowerCase :: [Char] -> Bool
lowerCase x = if all isLower (rmNumCh x) then True else False

num :: String -> Bool
num = any (`elem` "0123456789")

rmNumCh :: String -> String
rmNumCh [] = []
rmNumCh (x:xs) = if (x `elem` "0123456789._") then rmNumCh xs 
                                              else x:rmNumCh xs

localPart :: String -> String
localPart str
  | length str <= 24 && charact str && lowerCase str 
                     && num str && not (repeatedLocal str) = "E-mail Valido"
  | otherwise = "E-mail Invalido"
```

I think numbers and characters are not recognized as lower case, so I add a function which eliminates nums and specific caracters (rmNumCh) and use this in the 'lowerCase' function.
And I also think you shouldn't use recursion for the 'localPart' function, because all functions returning boolean values check for a whole string.

Comment: What other ways can i make the localPart? am new and still learning about the other ways i can work with functions

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```hs
import Data.Char(isLower)

charact :: String -> Bool
charact = not . any (`elem` "! #$%&'*+-/><=?^`{|}:,``[]];")

repeatedLocal :: String -> Bool
repeatedLocal [] = False
repeatedLocal (x:xs) = if elem x ['.','_'] then elem x xs else  repeatedLocal xs

lowerCase :: String -> Bool
lowerCase x = all isLower (rmNumCh x)

num :: String -> Bool
num = any (`elem` "0123456789")

rmNumCh :: String -> String
rmNumCh [] = []
rmNumCh (x:xs) = if x `elem` "0123456789._" then rmNumCh xs else x:rmNumCh xs

localPart :: String -> String
localPart str
  | foldl (\acc f -> f str && acc) True [(<=24).length,charact,lowerCase,num,not.repeatedLocal] = "E-mail Valido"
  | otherwise = "E-mail Invalido"
```

I use 'foldl' function.